# Intermingled primes

Tags: mathematics, grid-deduction, number-theory, primes

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #14: Think inside the (very small) box!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/monthly-topic-challenge-14-think-inside-the-very-small-box).</sub>

6 different, 3 digit primes are stacked here in two layers.
You only see the sum of overlapping digits.

[image]

Find the 6 primes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 6 different primes are:

> Row 1: 113
>  Row 2: 101
>  Row 3: 601
>  Column 1: 281
>  Column 2: 401
>  Column 3: 313

Deductions (I solved it with regular expressions in a list of all prime numbers from 101-997):

> ```
>  -> Column 2:  /[1-5]01/           -> 101, 401
>
>  -> Row 1:     /[12][14][0-5]/     -> 113, 211, 241
>
>  -> Row 2      /[1-9]0[0-2]/       -> 101, 401, 601, 701
>
>  -> Row 3:     /[1-7]0[0-4]/       -> 101, 103, 401, 503, 601, 701
>
>  -> Column 3:  /[35]1[13]/         -> 311, 313
>
>  -> Row 1:     /..3/               -> 113
>
>  -> Column 2:  /4../               -> 401
>
>  -> Row 2:     401                 -> 101, 601, 701
>
>  -> Column 1:  /2[832][0-6]/       -> 223, 233, 281, 283
>
>  -> Row 3      /^[46]/             -> 401, 601 -> 601
>
>  -> Column 3:  /..3/               -> 313
>
>  -> Row 2:     401, 601            -> 101, 701
>
>  -> Column 1:  /..1/               -> 281
>
>  -> Row 2:     /1../               -> 101
> ```